# Treating div of accordions as one

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a grid of accordions as follows:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class='accordion-left'>
            <h3>Left 1</h3>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class='accordion-right'>
            <h3>Right 1</h3>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="accordion-left">
            <h3>Left 2</h3>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-right">
            <h3>Right 2</h3>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I also have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Un4u/2/).

Since "Left 1" and "Right 1" are in the same parent `div` I was expecting that if I click "Left 1", both "Left 2" and "Right 2" would drop down together.  However, both just get misaligned.  If I click "Right 1," only "Right 2" drops down.  Furthermore, if the sibling divs of each accordion are of different heights, I also expect bottom row of divs to fall together according to tallest div.

How can I treat the a `div` of accordions as one entity?

Comment: I really could not view in my mind what you are trying to do. But if you want one panel to affect all others, they should be in same parent and ,second your code, they are not. They are on same 'grand' parent, no in same parent. And if you are using jquery ui, the height based on tallest div is standard. Maybe if you post your jquery code would helpe more.

Comment: @Leo, that jsfiddle link is all the code laid out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "clearfix hack": http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

On your accordions parent:

```
.accordion-parent:before, .accordion-parent:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.accordion-parent:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

There is no problem with accordions on the same line not having the same height (added in my demo)

See update: http://jsfiddle.net/2Un4u/8/

Comment: All great solutions, Edward and Nicolas.  I'll go with Nicolas's solution as it doesn't show the scroll bar if I add content to the accordion's div.  Thanks for the fast responses.

Comment: If you talk about the scroll inside the accordion item, it's just by adding `heightStyle: 'content'` property on the accordions ;-)

Comment: Well, then I like Edward's solution more.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `float`. Try use inline-block for your accordions. Also slightly adjust the width so that left and right are shown on the same line. Also, use 
vertical-align: top if you want them to align top vertically.

```
div {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.accordion-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.accordion-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Un4u/5/

Comment: Although I marked Nicolas R's response as the answer, I ended up using this because it was simpler.  Using the `float` property doesn't seem to be appropriate here.  In my version, I only had one class for the accordions, and I placed the `vertical-align` property inside the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a bit adding a container to both and instead of having left right, left right i group them in left left, right right. 
now the container has the width and the accordion will always be 100% of the container

http://jsfiddle.net/2Un4u/10/

> ```
>   <div class="container"> <!-- new class -->
>     <div class='accordion-left'>
>         <h3>Left 1</h3>
>         <div></div>
>     </div>
>     <div class='accordion-left'>
>         <h3>left 2</h3>
>         <div></div>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="container"> <-- new class
>     <div class="accordion-right">
>         <h3>right 1</h3>
>         <div></div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="accordion-right">
>         <h3>Right 2</h3>
>         <div></div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

```
.container{
    width: 50%;  /* define width */
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.accordion-left {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
.accordion-right {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This prevents the misalignment of the accordions on the bottom row, but the bottom row of accordions do not move together as one when either of the top row of accordions are clicked.